# I am trying to compile following code wrote in fortran but has many errors

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile this following code in gfortran compiler:

```
    do_cmd       = .not. is_group
do while (.not. EOF(unit=100) .and. .not. flag_stop)
    read (100, '(A)', iostat = ios) buf
    if (buf(1:1)=="#") then
        ! comment line
    elseif ((buf(1:2)=="v ") .and. do_cmd) then ! vertex
        read(buf(2:), *, iostat=ios) p(1), p(2), p(3)
        if (ios.ne.0) then
            print "(/,2x,'Error of reading vertex position from obj-file (line #'(I3)');')", line_index
            stop
        end if
```

But I get these errors when the code is compiling:

```
      do while (.not. EOF(unit=100) .and. .not. flag_stop)
                              1
      Error: Keyword argument requires explicit interface for procedure ‘eof’ at (1)
```

and;

```
     do while (.not. EOF(unit=100) .and. .not. flag_stop)
                   1
     Error: Function ‘eof’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

I will be so grateful if anyone could help me.

edit:
I'm very new in fortran and couldn't find out how eof function works in gfortran.

What does it mean using unit=100 in argument?
And also Thought it is a logical function by default. How should I implicit its type?

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for your useful links. I edited my question and asked the main purpose. It would be a great appreciate if you could help me in this way. Thanks.

Comment: `eof` not having an implicit type suggests that this is code that was meant for another compiler which supports that as a non-standard intrinsic.  [Or that it's massively broken code, but I'm going for the first.]  You probably want to determine what it is meant to do and then see how to implement its functionality in standard Fortran (or at least, Fortran plus gfortran extensions).

Comment: Seems like it is an DEC/Compaq/Intel and HP extension. You must rewrite the code to use the `iostat=` or `end=` specifier. http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0239.htm

Comment: The links I provided explained why explicit interface is necessary for keyword arguments. However, you probably don't have any `eof()` function in the first place, so you can't place it in a module as I would otherwise suggest. Is that your own code?

Comment: No It's not. I must use it for my project. and discover it! but It's a part of a monster toolbox

Comment: the code is not standard Fortran. It will not work with gfortran unless you rewrite it. There may well be more traps like this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `EOF` is not part of the Fortran Standard. At least I can't find it anywhere.

In most programming languages, **EOF** stands for "End of File", and it is fairly obvious to me that the `EOF` in your example is supposed to be a logical function that returns `.TRUE.` if and only if the read pointer associated with `unit` (in your case `100`) points to the end of the file.

You can use the `ios` variable to check whether an **EOF** was encountered during the read. In that case, it will be `-1`. You can then use the `exit` statement to immediately quit the loop.

If you don't like the `-1`, and you use a Fortran 2003 compatible compiler, you might even use the module `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV`, which provides (amongst other things) the parameter `IOSTAT_END`.

Here's a very simple example:

```fortran
program iso
    use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: u = 100
    character(len=80) :: buf
    integer :: ios

    open(unit=u, action='READ', status='OLD', file='data.dat')

    read_loop : do
        read(u, '(A)', iostat=ios) buf
        if (ios == IOSTAT_END) exit read_loop ! EOF
        if (buf(1:1) == '#') cycle read_loop ! This line is a comment
        write(*, *) buf
    end do read_loop

    close(u)

end program iso
```

One note though: This code is meant as an example. It only exits the loop if it encounters an **EOF** -- not if the `read` fails for any other reason. (There are some other reasons that the the read would fail.) If that other error is persistent, then this will lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: As I commented before, it is an intrinsic in Intel Fortran and some other compilers.

Comment: I guess this code is in ifort. But I couldn't find ifort compiler for Unix. Do you know how can I handle this toolbox?

Comment: @M.F. Which Unix? If Linux is enough I can't get how you can't find it https://www.google.com/search?q=intel+fortran+linux

Comment: I did not mean linux. My system is Mac OSX Yosemite  @Vladmir F .

Comment: @VladimirF Do you know how to get a (legal) free version of the Intel Fortran Compiler that doesn't expire after a year? Happy to use an older version. I do think I had a version once, but I can't find it any more.

Comment: @chw21 AFAIK the Intel compilers do not expire if you buy them. The support expires, but the license does not. Best to ask at their forum. If you mean the free student version, its license is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to try a user-defined `EOF` function (as shown below) to minimize the amount of code modifications; but because this function is rather inefficient, I guess it is probably better to rewrite the original code so as to utilize `iostat` in `read` statements directly (as suggested above)...

```
module eofmod    !<-- please save this in a separate file, compile, and link with other programs
implicit none
contains

logical function EOF( unit )
    integer, optional :: unit
    integer :: ios

    if ( .not. present( unit ) ) stop "no unit given"
    read( unit, *, iostat=ios )
    if ( ios == -1 ) then
        EOF = .true.
    else
        EOF = .false. ; backspace( unit )
    endif
end function

end module

program test
    use eofmod   !<-- needs to be inserted at the top of routines (or modules) where "EOF" is used
    implicit none
    character(200) :: buf

    open(10, file="test.dat", status="old")
    do while ( .not. EOF( unit=10 ) )
        read( 10, "(a)" ) buf
        print "(a)", trim( buf )
    enddo
    close(10)
end program
```